# Terminal command in fedora

Tags: apache, fedora

What does the `yum` and `-y` means

```
yum install httpd -y
```

new to fedora. please guide me.

the above code will install Apache server in fedora

Comment: Why is this question tagged "apache"?

Comment: This is off-topic here, btw. This is a place to ask _programming related questions_.

Comment: Just take a look at the documentation of the command, easiest by reading it's manual page: `man yum`.

Comment: @arkascha tagged Apache because it is the terminal code to install apache server.

Comment: This has nothing to do specifically with the apache http server. It could be any other package. This is about how to use yum command, so not a programming question.

Comment: Have a try over at the SuperUser sister page. That one deals with usage of systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yum` is a software package manager that installs, updates, and removes packages on `RPM-based systems`. It automatically computes dependencies and figures out what things should occur to install packages. yum makes it easier to maintain groups of machines without having to manually update each one using rpm.

`-y` means that we did't want to gave yes to install any package (here httpd)

`httpd` installs apache web server

Thanks for Support and advice